# Custom Fields in Function custom post type not working properly

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

[image: there is no dropdown list coming from custom fields , no thumbnail feature]I have been trying to design news as a custom post type and i have added the necessary code to the function.php page also. But still there are no dropdown list in custom fields section. here is my code

```
[![function news_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'News',
      'has_archive'=>true,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'description', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
    );
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_custom_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of adding a custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'description', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function news_custom_init() {
 $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Newss' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
            ),
      'has_archive'=>true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui'            => true,
      'show_in_menu'       => true,
      'query_var'          => true,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'description', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
    );
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_custom_init' );
```